# Is there a SQL function I can use to rotate a sequence number over a number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if this is even possible and I might be trying to over simplify something I should be using multiple line of SQL/help tables to break it down

Table1 - Will always have one row but the dates might change

[image]

Table2 - Can have up to 52 rows, one for each week, each time the query runs it could have between 1 - 52 rows

[image]

Table3 - It's a table with every calendar date until 2099

[image]

What i'm trying to do is write a query and join the three. I want a table of dates from table3 that are between the dates in table1, that's the easy bit

select a.date, a.day_of_week
from table3 a
join table1 b on a.date between b.date_from and b.date_to

I then need to rotate the week number(s) in table2 every 7 rows

So ideally my end result would look like this

[image]

If table 2 had a third row for a third week, then the first 7 week_no value from table3 would be 1, row 8-14 would be 2, 15-21 3 and 22-28 would go back to 1.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: windows functions like row_number, rank and dense_rank when used with PARITION by will get you your desired results

Comment: I use these functions often but can't think how to "reset" after the last week in table2, dense_rank will order table3 by a week, so get the sequence every 7 rows (days) but if I only have 2 weeks in table2 what happens with week 3 onwards?

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide a self-content query to generate test data like `with table1 as (...), table2 as (...), table3 as (...) select ...` Then people can easily approach your problem.

Comment: You can join table1 and table3 and take the day difference to figure out the week numbers.  SQL server has UNPIVOT functionality that can help you rotate the table2 into the form where each row represents a (week number, day-of-week) pair. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll skip the join to table3, as you don't explain how to translate `week_no` to a date.

That just leaves normalising your Table1, which is easy to do with `CROSS APPLY`...

```
SELECT
  table1.week_no,
  normalised.day_no,
  normalised.hours
FROM
  table1
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    (2, mon),
    (3, tue),
    (4, wed),
    (5, thu),
    (6, fri),
    (7, sat),
    (1, sun)
)
  normalised(day_no, hours)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb033f94ad0beca20a53345c0aef9071

Then you just need to join the normalised data on to the applicable date in your calendar table.

---

***EDIT:*** You still haven't explained how to map `week_no` to a particular `date`, so I'm going to guess...

I'm going to assume that `table1.date_from` is always the start of a week, and that as such the first row of `table2` always maps to the first seven dates - even if `table1.date_from` is a Wednesday.

As such, if `table1.date_from` ***is*** a Wednesday...

- The 1st date will be assigned `table2.wed` from row 1
- The 2nd date will be assigned `table2.thu` from row 1
- The 3rd date will be assigned `table2.fri` from row 1
- The 4th date will be assigned `table2.sat` from row 1
- The 5th date will be assigned `table2.sun` from row 1
- The 6th date will be assigned `table2.mon` from row 1
- The 7th date will be assigned `table2.tue` from row 1
- And then the 8th date will move on the the second row in `table2`

Which gives...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table3
    ON table3.date BETWEEN table1.date_from AND table1.date_to
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DAY, table1.date_from, table3.date) / 7 % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
)
  map_to_week_number(week_no)
INNER JOIN
  (
    table2
  CROSS APPLY
    (
      VALUES
        (2, mon),
        (3, tue),
        (4, wed),
        (5, thu),
        (6, fri),
        (7, sat),
        (1, sun)
    )
    normalised(dow, hours)
  )
    ON  table2.week_no = map_to_week_number.week_no
    AND normalised.dow = table3.dow
ORDER BY
  table3.date
```

***NOTE***: To keep the maths tidy, this first week in `table2` has `week_no == 0` *(not `1`)*

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0dc8028eebe60435d17a496987238074

Comment: Ah great CROSS APPLY! I haven't properly used this before. I haven't done anything with the week_no that comes from table2 and that's the challenge. So running the above but using the right data I get the same results

Comment: Hi Thanks again, sorry I've been trying to take the original snippet and try to solve it with no luck. the date_from in table one could be any day of the week, so if it starts on wednesday, the first five rows will be week 1 (or 0). It's the mapping of the week no i'm struggling with because it's in order of date and every 7 days, so after two weeks, the week number continues to increase, so I want week 3 to be week 1 and week 4 to be week 2, 5 to be 1, 6 to be 2 and so on..

Comment: I think i'm there now, thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `table3` with a weeknumber like this:

```
SELECT 
  [date],
  [dow],
  (datepart(wk,[date])-datepart(wk,(select min([date]) from table3))) % (select count(*) from table2) as wk1
FROM Table3
```

The week number will be 0-based, and will depend on the number of records in `table`.

[%](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the modulus operator.

Comment: Thanks, this helped as well.